# Keep getting 400 bad request on console for post request while the post is really happening on the UI

Tags: java, api

I'm trying to run below test :

```
       @Test(priority =1)
       public void PostNetwork() throws ClientProtocolException,      IOException {
        String postBody = new JSONObject(){{
        put("vlan", TestHelper.randomVlan());
        put("computeNodeGroups", new int[]{});
        put("name", TestHelper.randomString(5));
        put("virtualNetworkGroups",new int[]{});
        put("colocationPorts",new int[]{});
        }}.toString();
        System.out.println("POST BODY: " + postBody);
        Object response = super.post(postnetworks, postBody);
        //Assert.assertNotNull(response.createdDate);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+postnetworks);


        System.out.println(
            "-----------------------------------------");
        }
```

and this is the main test :

```
      public PostResponseType post(String url, String postBody, boolean        isNegative, int expectedStatusCode) throws ClientProtocolException,    IOException {
            HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headerMap.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + TestBase.getAccessToken(isNegative));

            System.out.printf("Sending request to %s\n", url);
            // Call the API
            CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = restClient.post(url, postBody, headerMap);

            // Assert that the request was successful
            int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, expectedStatusCode);
            // If the request fails, don't check the object structure
                if (expectedStatusCode / 100 != 2) {
                return null;
                }
            Header[] headersArray = closeableHttpResponse.getAllHeaders();

            // Print headers and response for debugging
            HashMap<String, String> allHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (Header header : headersArray) {
                allHeaders.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("Header Array-->" + allHeaders);
            System.out.println("statusCode: " + statusCode);

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("The response from post API: " + responseString);


            try {
                PostResponseType returnvalue = MAPPER.readValue(responseString, this.postResponseClass);
                return returnvalue;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Getting this on the console :

> POST BODY:
>   {"vlan":2400,"computeNodeGroups":[],"name":"onkhw","virtualNetworkGroups":[],"colocationPorts":[]}
>   statusCode: 400
>       The response from post API: Error
>           at BadRequestError.HttpError [as constructor] (/node_modules/routing-controllers/http-error/HttpError.js:27:23)
>           at new BadRequestError (/node_modules/routing-controllers/http-error/BadRequestError.js:20:28)
>           at VirtualNetworkController. (/home/site/wwwroot/app/controllers/virtual-network-controller.js:103:23)
>           at Generator.next ()
>           at fulfilled (/home/site/wwwroot/app/controllers/virtual-network-controller.js:16:58)
>           at 
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

But the post is really happening on the UI , so how can I get the 200 status since it is really doing the post.

Comment: 400 Status means - "the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications. " Please check the API url getting formed here.

Comment: I have change my code to:public void PostNetwork() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  String postBody = new JSONObject(){{
   put("vlan", TestHelper.randomVlan());
   put("computeNodeGroups", new int[]{});
   put("name", TestHelper.randomString(5));
   put("virtualNetworkGroups",new int[]{});
   put("colocationPorts",new int[]{});
  }}.toString();
  System.out.println("POST BODY: " + postBody);
  Object response = super.post(postnetworks, postBody);

Comment: getting: POST BODY: {"vlan":2788,"computeNodeGroups":[],"name":"jpqbd","virtualNetworkGroups":[],"colocationPorts":[]}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>com.qa.tests.NetworksTest$$Lambda$41/370475881@59221b97 . But nothing been posted on the UI

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names start with lowercase. Also, I see that you are using the "double brace initialization", however it is discouraged, since it actually produces an anonymous subclass, generating class loader overhead.

Comment: Thanks  – MC Emperor, I did change the naming convention , but which double brace are you referring too. Is it this one (){{ . Anyway still giving 400 after changing the naming convention.